# Windows Phone startscreen tile with no title using Cordova/Phonegap build?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, live-tile

I'm building a mobile app for Windows Phone 8 using Cordova/Phonegap Build. Is there a way to hide the tile title Windows Phone uses for the app in the start screen? The tile icon I have to use has a white background and WP displays a white title on the white background. I noticed other apps with a white tile background in the start screen do not show this title. I used a bigger white margin on the tile to 'hide' the title, but is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!
Nyquist